# Why second parameter is not filtering based on the criteria of the first?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx

I have an SSRS report using a cube. I am trying to set up cascading parameters where the second parameter will be filtered based on the first parameter. I've done this successfully before using a different cube, but now I'm having issues. The only thing different this time is that the two parameters are coming from different dimensions. After I select the first parameter option, the results in the second appear without being filtered. Instead, all results are returned.

This is the MDX for my first parameter:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
    [Ag].[Department].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
    [Ag].[Department].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Ag].[Department].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue], 
    [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
} ON COLUMNS, 
    [Ag].[Department].children
ON ROWS
    FROM [MyCube]
```

This is the MDX for the second parameter:

```
WITH  
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
      [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
      [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
      [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
SELECT 
{
      [Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
      [Measures].[ParameterValue],  
      [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
} ON COLUMNS, 
Descendants
(
      [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].[Domain],
      [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].[Unit]
)
ON ROWS 
FROM 
( 
      SELECT 
      ( 
            STRTOSET(@FirstParameter, CONSTRAINED) 
      ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [MyCube]
)
```

Please note that these are from two different dimensions in the same cube.

Any ideas why the data in the second parameter is not being filtered? Do I need some sort of filter condition added?

Please help
Thanks

Comment: While testing in SSMS, if you replace the `@FirstParameter` by some department, do you see filtering happening?

Comment: @SouravA, that's a good idea. I just tried it but unfortunately sill no filtering happening.

Comment: Good. That means there is an issue with the relationships you set up in your cube i.e. Departments have no relationship with `Qu`.

Comment: hello @Zolt - you can use the NonEmpty function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but it is not exactly what I was hoping for. I was hoping to have some proper working MDX to take care of the filtering. But here is what I did.

1. Left the MDX the way it is for the second parameter.
2. Went in to the properties for the second dataset.
3. Went to filters section.
4. Set Domain equal to @FirstParameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `NonEmpty` function with the set as the second parameter:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
    [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
    [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterValue]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    Descendants
    (
      [Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].[Domain]
     ,[Qu].[Qu Hierarchy].[Unit]
    )
   ,StrToSet
    (@FirstParameter
     ,CONSTRAINED
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```